# Quickly creating a list of structs in a new struct

Tags: ruby, struct, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to build a few primitive objects to store a graph:

```
Vertex = Struct.new(:parent, :rank)
Graph = Struct.new(:vertexes, :edges)
Edge = Struct.new(:weight, :endpoints)
```

The idea here is that `:endpoints` (and `:parent`) are Vertexes, and, naturally, `Graph` stores lists of Vertexes and Edges. I tried to set this up, and I ran into trouble:

```
[47] pry(main)> t_graph = Graph.new()
=> #<struct Graph vertexes=nil, edges=nil>
[48] pry(main)> t_graph[:vertexes] = Array.new(Vertex.new())
TypeError: can't convert Vertex into Integer
from (pry):48:in `initialize'
```

On the other hand, this works:

```
[49] pry(main)> t_graph[:vertexes] = [Vertex.new(), Vertex.new()]
=> [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>]
```

What's the efficient way to generate a mass of empty Vertexes in a Graph (or any such relation) for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to simply populate a list of Vertexes is to use `.times`, which seems kind of clumsy, but creates a list (I added an `:id` value):

```
t_verts = []
9.times do t_verts << Vertex.new end
[10] pry(main)> t_verts
=> [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=nil>]
```

This creates different objects.

```
[11] pry(main)> t_verts.each do |vert|
[11] pry(main)*   vert.id = rand  
[11] pry(main)* end  
=> [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.755245226082449>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.0167377598961559>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.759799975185007>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.613897002692335>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.0407847317079812>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.549475744759297>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.571876769381891>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.270800829904956>,
 #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.814754555208641>]
```

To add these en masse to a Graph, Simone's method can be used to add the list of Vertexes to the Graph:

```
def add_vertex(new_verts) # Adds or updates vertexes non-destructively
    new_verts.each do |new_vert|
      # first case, redundant insert
      if self.vertexes.include?(new_vert)
        warn "Vertex already exists in graph, no replacement done"
        # second case, update
      elsif not (update_vert = self.vertexes.select { |vert| vert.id == new_vert.id }).empty?
        self.vertexes[self.vertexes.index(update_vert)] = new_vert
        # third case, append new
      else
        self.vertexes ||= []
        self.vertexes << vertex
      end
    end
  end
```

It looks like I need to build a constructor method that builds the Graph from an adjacency list and weight list; I don't see a simple way to do this in one big step.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new) is not the standard way to initialize an array with a value. If you want to create an array with a Vertex instance, use

```
t_graph[:vertexes] = [Vertex.new]
```

As described in the documentation, `Array.new` takes either an array or a Fixnum size of the array.

> ```
> new(size=0, obj=nil)
> new(array)
> new(size) {|index| block }
> ```
>
> Returns a new array.
>
> In the first form, if no arguments are sent, the new array will be
>   empty. When a size and an optional obj are sent, an array is created
>   with size copies of obj. Take notice that all elements will reference
>   the same object obj.
>
> The second form creates a copy of the array passed as a parameter (the
>   array is generated by calling #to_ary on the parameter).

One more thing: you can omit parenthesis when there are no args.

```
t_graph[:vertexes] = [Edge.new, Edge.new]
```

instead of

```
t_graph[:vertexes] = [Edge.new(), Edge.new()]
```

Keep in mind you can add methods to Structs.

```
Graph = Struct.new(:vertexes, :edges) do
  def add_vertex(vertex)
    self.vertexes ||= []
    self.vertexes <<  vertex
  end
end

g = Graph.new
g.add_vertex(Vertex.new)
```

Comment: So would I just have to write a function that takes in an array of parents and ranks to create Vertexes for populating a test Graph? It seems overly complicated.

Comment: I updated my code a little bit. I didn't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve, but I posted an example to give you some basic ideas.

Comment: I tried using that appending method you gave above, but it seems to unpack the input; I end up with a flat Array in `a_graph.edges` populated with each of the stored values in each Vertex.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree a bit with Array.new not being useful here. Find below my use case which solves the posters problem, even though this has been displayed but not well explained above:

```
  [31] pry(main)> Vertex = Struct.new(:parent, :rank)
  => Vertex
  [32] pry(main)> Graph = Struct.new(:vertexes, :edges)
  => Graph
  [33] pry(main)> Edge = Struct.new(:weight, :endpoints)
  => Edge
  [34] pry(main)> t_graph = Graph.new()
  => #<struct Graph vertexes=nil, edges=nil>
  [35] pry(main)> t_graph[:vertexes] = Array.new(2) { Vertex.new }
  => [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>, #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>]
  [36] pry(main)> t_graph[:vertexes] = Array.new(2, Vertex.new )
  => [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>, #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil>]
```

As displayed on line `[35]` you can call `Array.new` supplying the number of elements you want in the array in this case 2 and what the elements should be in this case `Vertex.new`

James Edward Gray II did a talk on Avdi Grimm's podcast(no advert intent here) that clearly explains a very similar example

Comment: This seems to create multiple references to the same `Vertex` object.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I gave 2 approaches, the first one creates distinct objects, while the second creates multiple references

Comment: Wierd! I assume I made a mistake.