# Accessing attributes of Struct contained in Struct

Tags: ruby, struct

I may be making a major design error, but this is my first time working with Structs in Ruby.

[As detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577361/quickly-creating-a-list-of-structs-in-a-new-struct), I have three objects, Vertex, Edge, and Graph. Vertex has simple attributes (scalars), but Edge can have `:endpoints` which is a pair of Vertexes in an Array. Specifically, Edge has a scalar `:weight` and a Array of Vertexes `:endpoints`. Lastly, Graph stores `:vertexes` and `:edges`, which are Arrays of Vertexes and Edges.

```
Edge = Struct.new(:weight, :endpoints)
```

Since Graph is a Struct containing Structs, I created a method to get the scalar `weights` from the Graph:

```
Graph = Struct.new(:vertexes, :edges) do
  def get_weights()
    w = []
    self.edges.each do |ed| w << ed.weight end
  end

#truncated
end
```

However, if I run this, I get Edges, not scalar Integers:

```
[226] pry(main)> t_weights = [4,8,8,11,7,4,2,9,14,10,2,1,6,7]
=> [4, 8, 8, 11, 7, 4, 2, 9, 14, 10, 2, 1, 6, 7]

[227] pry(main)> t_edges.each_with_index.map do |ed,ind|
[227] pry(main)*   ed.weight = t_weights[ind]  
[227] pry(main)*   ed.endpoints = endpoints[ind]  
[227] pry(main)*   # p ed.weight  
[227] pry(main)* end  
t_grap = Graph.new(t_verts, t_edges)

=> #<struct Graph
 vertexes=
  [#<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.31572617312378737>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.24063512558288636>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.34820800389791284>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.86247407897408>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.4503814825928186>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.4020451841058619>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.09096934472128582>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.9942198795853134>,
   #<struct Vertex parent=nil, rank=nil, id=0.4393226273344629>], <truncated>
 edges=
  [#<struct Edge
    weight=4,
    endpoints=
     [#<struct Vertex
       parent=#<struct Vertex:...>,
       rank=0, <truncated>

[230] pry(main)> t_grap.get_weights
=> [#<struct Edge
  weight=4,
  endpoints=
   [#<struct Vertex
     parent=#<struct Vertex:...>,
     rank=0,
     id=0.6540666040368713>,
    #<struct Vertex
     parent=#<struct Vertex:...>,
     rank=0,
     id=0.7511069577638254>]>,
 #<struct Edge
  weight=8,
  endpoints=
   [#<struct Vertex
     parent=#<struct Vertex:...>,
     rank=0,
     id=0.6540666040368713>,<truncated>
```

I tried adding `attr_accessor :weights` to Edge, but then the code snippet above which sets the initial values fails silently, leaving each `Edge.weight` equal to `nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need vertices in the call to Graph.new

The edges should already contain them in the endpoints.

```
Vertex = Struct.new(:x, :y)
Edge = Struct.new(:weight, :endpoints)

Graph = Struct.new(:edges) do
  def get_weights
    edges.map(&:weight)
  end
end

e1 = Edge.new 66, [Vertex.new(1,2), Vertex.new(2,1)]
e2 = Edge.new 26, [Vertex.new(1,1), Vertex.new(2,1)]
g = Graph.new([e1,e2])
g.get_weights
=> [66, 26]
```

Edit:

```
g.edges.each { |edge| p edge.weight }
66
26
...
```

works. You might be building something different. The code above creates a Graph object that contains an array of Edge objects called edges.

```
ed_ary.map[&:weight]
```

won't work. As in my comment `g.edges.map(&:weight)` is just a shortcut. See this discussion: [What does to_proc method mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881125/what-does-to-proc-method-mean)

---

Comment: Definitely works, but I'm having trouble understanding the amp operator. If I just have an Array of Edges outside of the Graph, why doesn't either `ed_ary.each do |ed| p ed.weight end` or `ed_ary.map[&:weight]` return with the stored weights?

Comment: Sorry, I should have kept things familiar. It's the same as `edges.map { |edge| edge.weight }`